# Is it possible to send partial reply to the client and later send complete response?

Tags: grails-2.0

I use a payment gateway which uses the relay response url of my web application to return the transaction response or receipt information. The problem is that it uses a timeout i.e if it is 10 seconds since it made the request to the relay response url and if the relay response url didn't respond within that time then it will timeout. The problem i am trying to avoid or minimize is for the url to respond within the timeout period. One thing i have noticed is that this method that relay response url points to over the time has gotten bulkier and this may amount to the occasional timeouts that is happening. One solution i think could be to render partial response quickly like "Please wait...". If the payment gateway receives something from the relay response url then it shouldn't timeout. After that when the heavy processing is complete then the relay method sending full response which will be receipt in most cases. Is there a way to achieve this? I appreciate any help! The framework i am using for my application is grails 2.0.

I thought something like this would work but i was wrong.

```
def receiptFinal(){

...

}

def receipt(){
        render "Please wait..."
        redirect(controller: 'payment', action: 'receiptFinal')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes,it is quite possible I guess. Your payment gateway has to make two requests. One is to confirm whether validation/payment is all right or not. And, Second request to the client would be final response (like receipt etc)
It would totally depend on payment gateway.

--
Jitendra